# Source tree crashed and repository is messed

Tags: git, branch, project, commit, sourcetree

I use source tree for my project and I was doing a commit, source tree crashed and seeing that it didn't do the commit I tried to reverse the commit because it messed up the code.
I've attached an image where I explain the problem.
PLease, I ask for a kind help, It would really help me a lot.
**what I want to have is "Dropzone funzionante in IE8+,chrome,Mozilla" the main node set with origin/master, origin/head and head.The other things going up from this node I would like to delete them**.
I dont' know how to do it in source tree[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind, I've decided to delete the git since I had previous versions stored on my pc and to create a new one, rough to see and hear it was the fast and easy solution to do.